# How to Prevent CSRF in a Blazor Server App

Tags: csrf, blazor

I'm developing a blazor server web application and I've been reading about Cross Site Request Forgery vulnerabilities. I understand that the mitigation is to use anti-forgery tokens when a form is submitted so that a form in a malicious website won't be able to submit. But in a Blazor Server App, it uses SignalR so that the form doesn't really submit. It occurred to me that maybe Blazor Server apps aren't vulnerable to CSRF because the runspace is bound so that the session doesn't exist if you open a new tab or something like that, I'm pretty new to this stuff. So what's the go with CSRF and Blazor Server Apps?

Comment: I think this can help you: [link] https://remibou.github.io/CSRF-protection-with-ASPNET-Core-and-Blazor-Week-29/